# Access POST data (OAuth redirect code) on my Angular page

Tags: angularjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm new to AngularJS, and now I'm facing a problem. I've been searching/trying things for hours, yet nothing seems to work.

I once made a web app that connects with Google through OAuth 2.0, for retrieving Analytics data. It works just like intended, however I just converted my app to AngularJS, and suddenly OAuth isn't working anymore.

After some debugging, I found out that it wasn't able to retrieve the returned 'code' from the URL after logging in with my Google account and being redirected back to my page. My code stops working where it says:

```
if (isset($_GET['code'])) { // Do something }
```

*Note: If I skip this step, and just request data immediately without having a valid token, Google returns a 401: Login Required error. So there's nothing wrong with the connection or app credentials.*

The redirect URL looks like this:

*http://www.domain.com/app/?code=HaShCoDe#/app/dashboard* (where HaShCoDe is of course the returned code)

I've tried multiple things posted here for retrieving the 'code' from the URL, but my $_POST is always NULL. Maybe the problem is the '#/app/dashboard' *after* the post data, but that's just how this theme (which I bought) works, so I have to accept that.

Comment: The url is completely wrong. Url parameters are suppose to be after the hash parts - this is why it cannot be found.  You are a developer so "Maybe the problem is the '#/app/dashboard' after the post data, but that's just how this theme (which I bought) works, so I have to accept that" is just laziness

Comment: I can only set "domain.com/app" as my redirect URL, since Google doesn't accept a hashtag in one. Also, as far as I know, the hashtag is just how Angular works if you want compatibility with IE.

Comment: So why is the # appearing after the query parameter - are you setting this?

Comment: My redirect URL is www.domain.com/app, and somehow Angular (or this theme) automatically places "#/app/page" at the end of URLS, and there it's placed after the query parameter. I'm new to this whole Angular/MVC thing and I have no idea why and how this happens. I was hoping someone else has had the same problem and was able to help me. (theme is http://flatfull.com/themes/angulr)

Comment: It does seem to be angular - I just tried it - the $routeParams does not contain the code value if the query string is before the hash value.  You can get it via window.location.search though.  This appears to be an angular bug to me so you may want to file it with them.

Comment: Thanks for checking and pointing some thing out! I see window.location.search is working, so I'll use it to create some workaround then until I find a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However not *the best solution*, this workaround seems to fix it.

I noticed a few other people having exactly the same problem (for Google and other OAuth redirects), and still haven't been able to solve this, nor is there a fix from the Angular team (even though they seem to be aware of this problem), I'll post my solution here.

---

On your main page check if the access_token variable is set, and if not, create a link to a new page:

```
<? 
if(!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    echo '<a href="/link/to/analytics.php">Connect with Analytics</a>';
} 
?>
```

Now create a non-AngularJS page (see above, in my case analytics.php). Let that page handles the authorization. **Don't forget to set that page as the Redirect URI in Analytics**. Now, add the same access_token check on this page, and forward it automatically to your main page when the access_token is set.

```
<? 
if(isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    header('Location: http://www.mainpage.com/app');
} 
?>
```

And now `$_SESSION['access_token']` is available in your Angular JS app, and querying the Google servers work like they should.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the # in the url that angular uses. To work around this you can set the redirect without the path and handle the redirect like this

```
angular
  .module('angularoauthexampleApp', [
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/access_token=:accessToken', {
        template: '',
        controller: function ($location,$rootScope) {
          var hash = $location.path().substr(1);

          var splitted = hash.split('&');
          var params = {};

          for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
            var param  = splitted[i].split('=');
            var key    = param[0];
            var value  = param[1];
            params[key] = value;
            $rootScope.accesstoken=params;
          }
          $location.path("/about");
        }
      })
  });
```

Another way is to set $locationProvider.html5mode(true). This mode can work with just paths and makes seamless integration. However it may not work with older browsers

This is a complete example
http://anandsekar.github.io/oauth2-with-angularjs/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I knew about html5mode, but like you said, that breaks support for older browsers. I've fixed the issue now by using OAuth and API calls through javascript instead of PHP, which I actually should have done in the first place :)